# Sub-sites contributors and reader are unable to view the sub-site navigation

Tags: 2013, permissions, navigation, managed-metadata

I have created a term store using the site collection administrator. And I associate this term store with a sub site navigation.
But the problem I am facing is that the sub-site readers and even the contributors can’t see the sub site navigation. And when I check the term-store permission I can define the contributors group as in the below picture. but in this way reader of a sub site will be able to modify the term store which I do not want to happen.

[image]

BR